# Is it possible to change VSCode 3-way merge editor layout?

Tags: visual-studio-code, 3-way-merge

I've always liked using Meld to resolve conflicts with Git, mainly because we see 3 columns, the middle one being the column that contains the final result. Another feature that I really like that Meld offers is the option for you to hold down a key and it offers two options, to copy the highlighted line or copy up or down, very useful.

But unfortunately, Meld is not available for MacOS, I was using the "alternative" version that exists but a few weeks ago the app simply stopped working so I had to find an alternative.

I then decided to use VSCode itself for this, but despite not having all the features I mentioned in Meld, I would really like to at least be able to view the three panels side by side. Currently, "Incoming" is displayed on the left, "Current" on the right and "Results" at the bottom, but I would really like to make it similar to Meld, which is "Current" on the left, "Results" in the middle and "Incoming" on the right. It is possible?

[VSCode 3-way merge editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzHDG.png)